# How to provide an XPath for nearest ancestor?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

Disclaimer: I am aware that this question resembles very much [XPath to find nearest ancestor element that contains an element that has an attribute with a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005370/xpath-to-find-nearest-ancestor-element-that-contains-an-element-that-has-an-attr/40333166). Unfortunately, I do not quite understand completely how to select the closest/nearest ancestor?

This is my scenario. I am building an automated test for a webpage displaying several data "tables". Every "table" needs to be identified by its' `<label>` content rather than a normal `id`-attribute on the "table" (such `id` does not exist).

This image illustrates the structure I am working with (snapshot from chrome browser window):
[image]

This is essentials from corresponding pseudo html:

```
<root>
    ... 
    <div class="gridBox">  <!-- 1 -->
        <div class="gridBox"> <!-- 2 -->
        
            <div class="gridBox"> ... </div>
            
            <div class="gridBox">
                <label>In Progress and Rejected</label>  <!-- I want to start here -->
            </div>
            
            <div class="gridBox">
                <div class="gridBox">

                    <div class="table"> <!-- I want to identify this element -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="header">
                                <div class="column">...</div>
                            </div>
                            ...
                        </div>                      
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="cell">Value 1</div>
                            <div class="cell">Value 2</div>
                            ...
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gridBox">
        
            ...
            
            <div class="gridBox">
                <label>Await approval</label>
            </div>
            
            ...
    
        </div>
        <div class="gridBox">
        
            ...
            
            <div class="gridBox">
                <label>Approved</label>
            </div>
            
            ...
    
        </div>
    </div>
    
    ...
<root>
```

**Approach**
I want `<label>In Progress and Rejected</label>` to be the starting point. The next thing I want to do is climb up to this ancestor node: `<div class="gridBox"> <!-- 2 -->`. Finally, I want to find the contained descendant child node `<div class="table">`. A simple task?

**Question**
How to identify `<div class="gridBox"> <!-- 2 -->` starting from `//label[contains(.,"In Progress and Rejected") ]/ancestor::div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the `following::` axis rather than the `ancestor::` axis.

This XPath,

```
//label[normalize-space()="In Progress and Rejected"]
 /following::div[@class="table"][1]
```

selects the first `<div class="table">` element following the `label` whose space-normalized string value equals the targeted text.

See also [Difference between child, following and descendant in XPath axes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49966055/290085)

Comment: I was not aware that it was possible to use `/following` on other nodes than immediate siblings. Thank you for the (entire!) solution, it works very well! :-)

Comment: @HaunsTM:  You're welcome.  I added a link you might find helpful to a Q/A that elaborates on the XPath axes.